# SignalR Javascript Client Error: Dynamic file not generated

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Here is the screenshot of runtime project that contains signalR.
[image]

There is no hubs file generated.
 I am getting the most common javascript error That is also shown in picture.
I searched and found many solutions but nothing seems to work.
like changing reference src and etc.
Here is how I am referencing the script files.

```
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>
```

Please advice something on this. The code is the sample code from microsoft docs. [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

> **EDIT1:**
>
> After a more research and changing some lines, Now hubs file is
>   present, I can see  there is no signalR JS file during runtime.and the
>   error is -
>
> 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SignalR: SignalR is not loaded. Please ensure jquery.signalR-x.js is referenced before ~/signalr/js.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer.
I was trying every possible thing I got on internet and then one thing worked.
and that was in this line **[HubName("myHub")].**. I had this name as **[HubName("MyHub")]** before and so the error.

```
  [HubName("myHub")]

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        // public static string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CresijCamConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
```

You need to define HubName same as you used in javascript so that there wont be any confusion in getting client.

> var chat = $.connection.myHub;